# Slants cross over responsive

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to create similar to the attached with HTML/CSS, that works responsive? without using am image?

Unable to get the oragne border & content added in
CSS

```
.left {

  border-bottom: 70px solid #3488b1;
  border-right: 1000px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
 width: 1px;
 opacity:.5;
 }
.right {
  border-bottom: 70px solid #3488b1;
  border-left: 1000px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
 width: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
}

 .footer {height:100px;}
```

& HTML

```
<div class="footer">
<span class="left"> </span>
<span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

[image: Is there anyway to create similar to the attached with HTML/CSS]

Comment: yes. What have you tried?

Comment: A good starting point is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have the the triangles as @AliGajani has mentioned but i cant get them full width. or with the orange border on top of the parent one.

Comment: Show us your code and/or put on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use transforms.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#responsive {
    position:relative;
    height:25%;
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height: 80px;
}
#triOne {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:aqua;
    height:300%;
    width:300%;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    top:55%;
    left:-100%;
}
#triTwo {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    height:300%;
    width:300%;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
    top:45%;
    right:-100%;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive">
    <div id="triOne"></div>
    <div id="triTwo"></div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

It's not really responsive, but I think with a few tweaks you should be able to get it the way you want it.

Comment: He is not talking about this friend.

Comment: @UI-UX I edited a little because the first version was wrong, but I think the method is valid.  I'd love to learn of a different method, though.

Comment: @JosephMalle that is great thanks - a few small tweaks to responsive css & this should work (on face of it)

Comment: @Mel Glad it works! Let me know if it runs into trouble.